# Jquery undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, undefined

estoy usando VS 2013 para crear una vista maestro detalle, por ahora cuando hago click en el listado con Jquery me debería salir el Id del registro, pero me sale undefined

```
 @model IEnumerable<MasterDetailsMVC4.Models.Orders>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

@section styles{
    <style>
        .highlight {
            background-color: rgb(230,244,224);
        }
    </style>
    }

@section scripts{
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#master tbody tr").click(function () {
                $(this).addClass('highlight').siblings().removeClass('highlight');                
                var Id = this.cells[0].textContext;
                alert(Id);
            });
        });
    </script>
    }
    <h1>Master details using asp.net mvc 4</h1>
<br\></br\>
<h2>Orders</h2>

<table class="table " id="master">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CustomerID)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EmployeeID)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.OrderDate)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RequiredDate)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ShippedDate)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ShipVia)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Freight)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ShipName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ShipAddress)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ShipCity)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ShipRegion)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ShipPostalCode)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ShipCountry)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CustomerID)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmployeeID)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OrderDate)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RequiredDate)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ShippedDate)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ShipVia)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Freight)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ShipName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ShipAddress)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ShipCity)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ShipRegion)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ShipPostalCode)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ShipCountry)
            </td>

        </tr>
    }

</table>


<h2>Orders Details</h2>

<table class="table " id="details">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CustomerID)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EmployeeID)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.OrderDate)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RequiredDate)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ShippedDate)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ShipVia)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Freight)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ShipName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ShipAddress)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ShipCity)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ShipRegion)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ShipPostalCode)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ShipCountry)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>


    <tr>
        <td colspan="13">
            <p>Seleccione una orden</p>
        </td>


    </tr>


</table>
```

¿Qué cambios debo hacer?
*************************edición***********
Este es el html generado

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Home Page - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    <link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>


    <style>
        .highlight {
            background-color: rgb(230,244,224);
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>






    <h1>Master details using asp.net mvc 4</h1>
<br\></br\>
<h2>Orders</h2>

<table class="table " id="master">
    <tr>
        <th>
            CustomerID
        </th>
        <th>
            EmployeeID
        </th>
        <th>
            OrderDate
        </th>
        <th>
            RequiredDate
        </th>
        <th>
            ShippedDate
        </th>
        <th>
            ShipVia
        </th>
        <th>
            Freight
        </th>
        <th>
            ShipName
        </th>
        <th>
            ShipAddress
        </th>
        <th>
            ShipCity
        </th>
        <th>
            ShipRegion
        </th>
        <th>
            ShipPostalCode
        </th>
        <th>
            ShipCountry
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                VINET
            </td>
            <td>
                5
            </td>
            <td>
                04/07/1996 12:00:00 a.m.
            </td>
            <td>
                01/08/1996 12:00:00 a.m.
            </td>
            <td>
                16/07/1996 12:00:00 a.m.
            </td>
            <td>
                3
            </td>
            <td>
                32,38
            </td>
            <td>
                Vins et alcools Chevalier
            </td>
            <td>
                59 rue de l&#39;Abbaye
            </td>
            <td>
                Reims
            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                51100
            </td>
            <td>
                France
            </td>

        </tr>
```

Comment: Podrías dar un ejemplo del html al cual quieres hacer referencia.

Comment: Claro, esta es toda la vista @Samir Llorente

Answer (score 0):

Cuando haces [0] ya pierdes todas las opciones (metodos y variables) de jquery. Utiliza ´find´ para seguir filtrando y para obtener el texto del html usa la funcion ´text´, te quedaria asi

```js
$(function () {
    $("#master tbody tr").click(function () {
        $(this).addClass('highlight').siblings().removeClass('highlight');                
        var Id = $(this).find('th:nth-child(1)').text();
        alert(Id);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

<table class="table" id="master">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: En VS me saca un cuadro de texto vacío, podrías ejecutarlo en VS? Aquí está el proyecto [enlace]https://mega.nz/#F!Wn4g1Qha!L1-0bkz78DtU-q1bqPih3g[/enlace] @Samir Llorente